# Random query results based on session

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a profiles table that I would like to have list profiles in Random order which I have accomplished like so:

```
$this->paginate = array('User' => array('conditions'=>array('User.userstanding_id'=>'1'), 'order' => 'RAND()', 'limit' => '10'));
```

The only functionality that is missing from this is that, I would like the profiles to follow sequentially so that on the next page there are not duplicates and even some profiles don't get viewed at all when you make it through all of the pages.

What I am looking for is a way to find a random starting point for the query then paginate in order from that starting point. Maybe per Session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL [`RAND()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) can take an integer as an argument to use as a seed, always producing the same result:

To demonstrate this, here's a table with 3 single-column string records in it:

```
mysql> select * from chartest;
+--------+
| string |
+--------+
| AA     |
| AB     |
| BB     |
+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If I use 1 as my seed value for the `rand()` in my `ORDER BY` it will always produce the same result ordering:

```
mysql> select * from chartest order by rand(1);
+--------+
| string |
+--------+
| BB     |
| AA     |
| AB     |
+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from chartest order by rand(1);
+--------+
| string |
+--------+
| BB     |
| AA     |
| AB     |
+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If I change my seed to 2, the ordering changes:

```
mysql> select * from chartest order by rand(2);
+--------+
| string |
+--------+
| AB     |
| BB     |
| AA     |
+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

#### Choosing your seed

You could convert the user's session ID to an integer and pass it in to this function so that for that session, the results would always be ordered in the same way.

If for example the session ID is an MD5 hash, to avoid having to deal with large (160 bit) integers that these values represent, just strip the characters from the string (using, for example `preg_replace ('/[^\d\s]/', '', $sessionid);`). Then take the first 5 or so digits and convert that to an `(int)` to use as your seed:

```
$seed = substr($numeric_id, 0, 5);
```

#### Update

To pass the parameter to the `RAND()` function when using CakePHP, to ensure it's treated as an integer rather than a string, try using the following syntax in your `$conditions` array's `order`:

```
'order' => 'RAND(CAST('.$seed.' AS SIGNED))'
```

Comment: cake is turning the query into this ORDER BY `rand(\`3\`)` and throwing errors. I am not adding the ` it is automatic by cake. I'm assuming that is where the error is coming from... Any ideas? sorry ... there are tics around the 3...

Comment: I would normally suggest storing your integer in a a proper PHP variable of type `(int)`, and binding it rather than concatenating it, but since you're using cake, try passing it in as per my update above.

Comment: Glad to hear it :) I'm not sure why Cake decides to mangle your `int` into a `char` though - not exactly "helpful behaviour" is it.

Comment: No, heh, not helpful at all... I actually had to add spaces to get around it. '('.$seed.')' became '( '.$seed.' )'. But your initial answer to my rand question worked great.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert with CakePHP but I imagine if you seed the RAND function on a session basis then paginate function will work from page to page using the session seed value.

e.g

assign seed at creation of session, just use a random number generator to do this.

```
 $this->paginate = array('User' => array('conditions'=>array('User.userstanding_id'=>'1'), 'order' => 'RAND('.$_SESSION['rndSeed'].')', 'limit' => '10'));
```